# Calculate values from input based upon select option

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know of a link that will help me to learn how to do the following. I've Googled for assistance but cannot find a specific answer.

I have the following setup.

```
<div class="information">
<input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input class="income" id="input_1_income" type="text" placeholder="After Tax Income">
<select class="option">
    <option>Week 1</option>
    <option>Week 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I have 6 of these on my page. The inputs with the placeholder "After Tax Income" all have a different ID; the number changes from a 1 through to a 6.

What I'm attempting to do is have the numbers that are entered into the inputs added together based upon the select option of the week, either Week 1 or Week 2, and then that answer will be displayed in one of the following inputs.

```
<div id="div2">

    <div class="time">
    <input class="finance" type="text"> <br>
    <label>Week 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    <input class="finance" type="text"> <br>
    <label>Week 2</label>
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    <input class="finance" type="text"> <br>
    <label>Fortnightly</label>
    </div>

    <div class="time">
    <input class="finance" type="text"> <br>
    <label>Yearly</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

So basically all of the Week 1 values will be added together and displayed in the week 1 input, all of the week 2 values added together and displayed in the input. Then I need to calculate Week 1 and Week 2 together and have that displayed in the Fortnightly input and then have the fortnightly input multipled by 26 and have that answer displayed in the yearly input.

I've been searching for some jQuery to assist in this but to no avail. I'm extremely new to jQuery so and guidance to the right links or and material to read in general would be a blessing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle to play with**](https://jsfiddle.net/dwbah309/)</kbd>

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  updateDiv2();
});
function updateDiv2(){
 wSel=0, ati=0, wk1=0, wk2=0;
 $('select').each(function(){
   ati = $(this).prev().val(); //.income
   ati = (ati>0)?ati:0; //if empty, make value zero (prevent NaN)

   if (this.value.split(' ')[1] == 1){
    wk1 = parseInt(wk1) + parseInt(ati);
   }else{
    wk2 = parseInt(wk2) + parseInt(ati);
   }
   $('#ttl_wk1').val(wk1);
   $('#ttl_wk2').val(wk2);
 });
}
```

```css
.time {overflow:hidden;}
.time input{float:left;}
.time label{float:left;width:80px;text-align:right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="information">
 <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
 <input class="income" id="input_1_income" type="text">
 <select class="option">
  <option>Week 1</option>
  <option>Week 2</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="information">
 <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
 <input class="income" id="input_1_income" type="text">
 <select class="option">
  <option>Week 1</option>
  <option>Week 2</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="information">
 <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
 <input class="income" id="input_1_income" type="text">
 <select class="option">
  <option>Week 1</option>
  <option>Week 2</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div id="div2">
 <div class="time">
  <label>Week 1</label>
  <input id="ttl_wk1" class="finance" type="text"> <br>
 </div>
 <div class="time">
  <label>Week 2</label>
  <input id="ttl_wk2" class="finance" type="text"> <br>
 </div>
 <div class="time">
  <label>Fortnightly</label>
  <input id="ttl_fn" class="finance" type="text"> <br>
 </div>
 <div class="time">
  <label>Yearly</label>
  <input id="ttl_yr" class="finance" type="text"> <br>
 </div>
</div>
```